# Python - Filter matrix between two values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list L and a matrix X in which I need to perform some operations. One of the operations is to filter the list and matrix between two certain values. In Matlab this looks like:

```
L_new = L(L> 5 & f_i < 9);
X_new = X(:, L > 5 & L < 9);
```

So this works, but now I need to have this in Python. For the list L I got something that worked:

```
L_new = [i for i in L if i > 5 and i < 9]
```

Does someone know the Python code for the matrix operation done in Matlab?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np    

X_new = np.array([[i for i in x if i > 5 and i < 9] for x in X])
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks! It does work, but I end up with a list somehow instead of a matrix.

Comment: @GaneshGebhard It will be a list of lists which is a matrix. Can you please comment the input and the desired output?

Comment: The input will take some time to give here, but the desired output would be a matrix (nxm). Now it's simply a list of length n.

Comment: @GaneshGebhard i have edited the answer. please check if you are looking for same, I would still like to see the desired output as list of lists is a MATRIX only.

Comment: I get the error: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 0):

Python's standard library doesn't have direct support for matrices or higher dimensional tensors. You can work with nested lists for overcome that, as the other answers have suggested.

I'd recommend to check out `numpy` for this problem, for example the [linear algebra module](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.linalg.html).

If you wanted to e.g. clip your values to 5 and 9, you could do the following:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
print(arr)
> [[0 1 2]
   [3 4 5]
   [6 7 8]]

arr_clipped = np.clip(arr, a_min=5, a_max=9)
print(arr_clipped)
> [[5 5 5]
   [5 5 5]
   [6 7 8]]
```

If you want to set these values to zero, you can use a mask:

```py
mask = (5 <= arr) & (arr <= 9)
arr_masked = np.where(mask, arr, 0)
print(arr_masked)
> [[0 0 0]
   [0 0 5]
   [6 7 8]]
```